# Is it possible to add a custom footer to Swashbuckle Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swagger UI to document an API and everything is working great. I'm wondering if it is possible to add a custom footer to the generated web page? I know that there are different ways of writing documentation elements throughout the page and injecting CSS and JavaScript files. But is there an easy way to put a chunk of HTML in the footer?

Comment: How to you run/host Swagger UI? Do you simply use the assets from [`dist`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist), or do you use Swagger UI provided as part of some framework e.g. Swashbuckle or Springfox? Or some other way?

Comment: I'm adding swagger ui through Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-indexhtml

Comment: I was thinking about something like that. But would prefer not to replace the entire index.html file if possible. I probably need to, but would be nice with just a simple insert HTML or something like that. One thing I'm considering is to include it using an injected JavaScript. But would be cool to tell swagger UI to generate this as part of the initial request.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can !!  you need to override the swagger templates.

example:-  if you are using django project so you can find the file like this.

```
virtual_environment->lib->python->site-package->swagger->templates->swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: While I acknowledge that overwriting the template is a possibility, I'm looking for another way to do it. I want to be able to upgrade to new swagger ui versions without having to rebuild a new template each time. Thanks.

Comment: if you are using default UI of any upgraded version that will be best but sometimes that is  not enough as per our requirements then you can go for mentioned approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like you are looking for an "easy" way to do it...
No such a thing with Swashbuckle right now,
...but you could propose a feature similar to what's already in place for `%(HeadContent)`

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/index.html#L31

is not too much just a few hits on that:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=HeadContent&unscoped_q=HeadContent

Request the new feature with an issue:
 https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new
or send a PR with a new `%(FooterContent)` and bingo that will be really easy moving forward